# Crear una tabla temporal en un store procedure dentro de un paquete - Oracle

Tags: oracle

Tengo el siguiente stored procedure dentro de un paquete; en el siguiente SELECT lo pongo en un **WITH**, seguidamente para obtener 2 campos y hacer un INSERT en una tabla, en el cursor quiero hacer un `select * from PREDATA` (nombre del WITH) pero me sale error, como puedo insertar todo el select del **WITH** dentro de una tabla temporal, caso que en mi cursor solo haría lo siguiente: `SELECT * FROM "TEMP1"`

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY SAR_PRG_REPORTE21  
AS   
PROCEDURE REPORTE_21(P_FECHA varchar2, P_NIVEL1 out TCURSOR)  
  AS  
  begin   

   INSERT INTO SAR.A01_REPORTE21(periodo,id_vinculado)
   WITH PREDATA 
    AS (
       SELECT 
        c.id_cliente,
       c.codigo_deudor_sbs,
       c.razon_social,
       c.codigo_ciiu,
       c.direccion

      FROM tae.tae_cliente c
      WHERE c.VINC_EMPRESAS <> '9'
    )
SELECT substr(P_FECHA,0,6),ID_CLIENTE FROM PREDATA;

**Edité**
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE PREDATA_RESULT   ---Error de Sintaxis: reglas parcialmente reconocidas
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS
INSERT INTO PREDATA_RESULT
SELECT * FROM PREDATA;
```

---===============================================

```
---AQUI DEBERIA DE INSERTAR "PREDATA" A UNA TABLA TEMPORAL CREADA--

OPEN P_NIVEL1 FOR 

    --SELECT * FROM PREDATA;  (SALE ERROR QUE NO EXISTE LA TABLA O VISTA)

    --AQUI DEBERIA DE REALIZAR UN SELECT DE LA TABLA TEMPORAL CREADA
END REPORTE_21;
END SAR_PRG_REPORTE21;
```

Muchas Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu pregunta?

Answer (score 2):

La sintaxis de tu CTE es correcta.

Sin embargo, después de esa inserción, PREDATA no existe; sólo están los datos insertados en la tabla destino y el origen de tu CTE ya no está disponible. Consultar a PREDATA en instrucciones posteriores siempre dará error.

**Edito**:

En Oracle, creo que desde la versión 10g, se pueden crear tablas temporales pero estas deben definirse como cualquier tabla, existen constantemente y sólo los datos son volátiles, desapareciendo al cerrar la sesión que los está usando:

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE PREDATA_RESULT(order_id NUMBER,...)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
...
INSERT INTO PREDATA_RESULT
SELECT ...
```

Esta aproximación sólo requiere crear la tabla en cualquier momento antes de usarla. Igual, sólo la tienes que crearla una vez, como cualquier otra tabla. Recuerda revisar la [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_7002.htm#SQLRF54447), en especial la opción `ON COMMIT`, que puede ser DELETE ROWS para borrar todo al hacer commit, o PRESERVE ROWS que mantiene los datos en la tabla hasta que termine la sesión que los creó.

Así, si insertas los datos con el CTE en la tabla temporal, mientras no hagas commit, puedes hacer un select común y corriente sobre la tabla más adelante en el procedimiento almacenado (en vez del `SELECT * FROM PREDATA`, harías un `SELECT * FROM TEMPTABLE`).

Desde [Oracle18](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/admin/managing-tables.html#GUID-9B373086-0760-4B18-9688-BACFF07EC74B) hay tablas temporales privadas, en memoria y single-session

```
CREATE PRIVATE TEMPORARY TABLE ora$predata_result AS
SELECT 
    c.id_cliente,
   c.codigo_deudor_sbs,
   c.razon_social,
   c.codigo_ciiu,
   c.direccion

  FROM tae.tae_cliente c
  WHERE c.VINC_EMPRESAS <> '9';
```

Comment: Respuesta editada.

Comment: Gracias Alfabravo, en mi caso sería el primer ejemplo, que también lo había encontrado; no sé si podrías ayudarme con lo siguiente: de acuerdo al procedure que envié, en que parte incluyo el ejemplo que me acabas de enviar,  tanto como el **CREATE GLOBAL** y cómo hago el llamado de la tabla temporal, 
psdt: cuando lo ingreso debajo del **BEGIN** me da error
gracias.

Comment: @AlexanderDaniel Por favor, edita la pregunta con la información que  falta. Incluye la creación de la tabla temporal y la forma en la que intentas usarla, así como el error que arroja.

Comment: Hola @AlfaBravo justamente es lo que quiero saber, en que parte de mi código debo incluir la creación de la tabla temporal y volver a llamarlo para realizar el select, si te das cuenta utilizo un **WITH PREDATA** todo ese select quiero incluirlo dentro de una tabla temporal, gracias de antemano.

Comment: Edité la respuesta aclarando eso. Como no sé qué quieres hacer con el cursor de entrada, hasta acá puedo llegar.

Comment: Edité mi pregunta, intento crear la tabla temporal e insertar toda la consulta del **WITH** pero me da error justo en la línea del **CREATE**  _Error de Sintaxis: reglas parcialmente reconocidas_ o es que lo estoy incluyendo en una línea incorrecta?

Comment: Creo que no fui claro: PREDATA existe sólo mientras haces el insert en A01_REPORTE21. Después ***NO EXISTE***. Así mismo, la tabla temporal hay que crearla ANTES de ejecutar el procedimiento y claramente ANTES de insertar datos.

Comment: gracias por tu aporte, pero la verdad soy casi nuevo en oracle, podrias apoyarme mandandome casi el mismo store que hice en la pregunta e incluir esa creacion de la tabla y donde llamarlo por favor?, enserio te lo agradecería mucho.

Answer (score -1):

```
/*********************inicio de registro  de las ventas ************************/
PROCEDURE SP_TICKET_REGISTRO_HISTORICA
IS
BEGIN
 DECLARE
    V_FECHA_HORA DATE;
 BEGIN
    V_FECHA_HORA:=SYSDATE;
    INSERT INTO PRD_WEB.TICKET_SIN_RESPONDER_APP 
    (SIS_TIC_ID,ESTADO_TICKET,ESTADO_WF,COD_ERROR_ATIS_CMS, SUB_DETALLE,FECHA_EJECUCION,FECHA_RESPUESTA_APP,FECH_REG_HISTORICO)
    SELECT s.SIS_TIC_ID,s.ESTADO_TICKET,s.ESTADO_WF,s.COD_ERROR_ATIS_CMS,s.SUB_DETALLE,'','',V_FECHA_HORA from PRD_WEB.sis_ticket s,PRD_WEB.workflow w
    where s.sis_tic_id=w.sis_tic_id (+)
    and  w.sis_ws_d_id(+)=16 AND  w.WOR_ERROR IS NULL AND  s.TIP_TRX_CMR_CD NOT IN (5,8,9,10,11,12) 
    AND s.COD_MOD_VEN_CD NOT IN (3,6,9,10) AND  trunc(s.fecha_reg_web)=trunc(sysdate-1);

 COMMIT;        
 END;
END SP_TICKET_REGISTRO_HISTORICA;
/*********************fin de registro*********************************************************************************/
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. ¿Por qué afirmas que este código responde la pregunta? ¿Cómo debería usarlo el OP? Procura que tus respuestas sean algo más que código para que le sirvan a quien pregunta y a todos los que tengan el mismo problema en el futuro. Puedes editar la respuesta usando el enlace que está justo debajo e incluir más información.